# Big S issue for comments in the iOS app

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, plurals

If your comment is long enough you can see the following:

> [image: left]
>
> [image: long]

P.S.: Please don’t [remind me about Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) any more.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPad Pro 10.5" (Wi-Fi only) (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.2.1 (Build 15C153)

Comment: Jeff? If you actually saw Kasra, you'd wonder why anyone would actually even worry about Jeff at any point in time. That guy could eat Jeff's giant S and still fool the dentist into thinking that he flossed. May Zod have mercy on your plural.

Comment: Interesting title: **Big S** issue, hahaha.

Comment: @PeterMortensen There's no space for product types for Apple's mobile devices, e.g. `iPad2,1`, `iPhone7,3`.